# Update item in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a list of birthdays and if the birthday is over it should add a year(in milliseconds) to that item on firebase. The main problem im having is that how to access the exact item to add the year. Firebase items werent added through the app thats why i cant use the getKey. Here are the pictures.

```
if(daysLeft<0){
     mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CODEFROGDB).child(/*here i need to get to the item*/).child("bday_p").setValue(model.getBday_p() + 31556952000L);
}
```

[image: Firebase Database PICTURE]

Comment: Do you have access to the previous value? I mean the value before adding 1 year

Comment: Yes, it prints in my list in the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simples way in which you can achieve this, is using the following code:

```
if(daysLeft<0) {
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CODEFROGDB)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Long bday_p = ds.child("bday_p").getValue(Long.class);
                    if(bday_p < now) {
                        ds.child("bday_p").getRef().setValue(bday_p + 31556952000L);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: This ads a year to each user not only to them who have the date -1 for example

Comment: You did not mention this constraint in your question but please see my updated answer in which i have added an if statement, `if(bday_p == -1)`. Is it ok now?

Comment: Now nothing changed, i mean the data didnt increase for one year for those persons whose birthday already is gone. The thing that it increases the birthday of all users not only the persons whose birthday was a week ago

Comment: But what happened then?

Comment: It increases the value bday_p in the database for all items, not only for those people whose birthday has already passed

Comment: Please see again my updated answer. Now it will update only the users that have the current time grater than now. With other words, whose birthday has already passed. Right?

Comment: Again it increases all of them, only with those that the birthday is smaller than one should increase the others should stay the same

Comment: I did not understand the last sentence. Can you please rephrase. Or give a concrete example.

Comment: Its working now i just changed the day < now, Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! I just updated my answer with the `<` sign. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the previous value to query for the item to be updated:

```
if(daysLeft<0){
     mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CODEFROGDB)
            .orderByChild("bday_p")
            .equalTo(model.getBday_p())
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CODEFROGDB)
                    .child(dataSnapshot.getKey())
                    .child("bday_p").setValue(model.getBday_p() + 31556952000L);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens